# Switch multiple case and multiple return in Vue/Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, switch-statement

I have such a table that shows about Exam Result. The status consists of 2 types, `Active` & `Nonactive`. And then further divided into 4 conditions: `Remind`, `Reminded`, `Correction` and `Corrected`. I have managed to condition it to change the buton color & text with `if else` in a methods like this:

```
methods: {
    getColorBtn(status, isCorrect, isRemind, textButton) {
      if (status === 1 && isCorrect === 1 && isRemind === 1) return 'v-btn--outlined theme--light primary--text'
      if (status === 1 && isCorrect === 0 && isRemind === 1) return 'primary plain--text'
      if (status === 0 && isCorrect === 0 && isRemind === 1) {
        return 'v-btn v-btn--text theme--light success--text shadow-none'
      }
      if (status === 0 && isCorrect === 0 && isRemind === 0) {
        return 'v-btn v-btn--text theme--light primary--text shadow-none'
      }

      return 'primary'
    },
    textButton(status, isCorrect, isRemind, textButton) {
      if (status === 1 && isCorrect === 1 && isRemind === 1) return 'Corrected'
      if (status === 1 && isCorrect === 0 && isRemind === 1) return 'Correction'
      if (status === 0 && isCorrect === 0 && isRemind === 1) return 'Reminded'
      if (status === 0 && isCorrect === 0 && isRemind === 0) return 'Remind'

      return 'primary'
    },
    getIcon(status, isCorrect, isRemind, textButton) {
      if (status === 1 && isCorrect === 1 && isRemind === 1) return 'd-none'
      if (status === 1 && isCorrect === 0 && isRemind === 1) return 'd-none'
      if (status === 0 && isCorrect === 0 && isRemind === 1) return mdiBellCheckOutline
      if (status === 0 && isCorrect === 0 && isRemind === 0) return mdiBellOutline

      return ''
    },
    getColorChip(status) {
      if (status === 1) return 'v-chip-light-bg success--text'

      return 'v-chip-light-bg error--text'
    },
}
```

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4llJz.png)

The data() (Btw, I just show it with 1 data as example here. Just to show the structure to y'all):

```
data() {
    return {
      isHide: true,
      icons: {
        mdiBellOutline,
        mdiBellCheckOutline,
      },
      students: [
        {
          no: '1',
          thumbnail,
          name: 'Ridho Mckinnon',
          status: 1,
          time: ' 08:04 - 09:58, 19/01/2021',
          isCorrect: 1,
          isRemind: 1,
        },
    }
}
```

The template:

```
<v-row>
    <v-col
        xl="2"
        lg="2"
        md="2"
        sm="6"
        cols="12"
    >
        <v-chip
        class="text-subtitle-2 text-md-caption text-lg-caption text-xl-caption"
        :color="getColorChip(student.status)"
        >
        {{ `${student.status ? 'Active': 'Nonactive'} ` }}
        </v-chip>
    </v-col>
    <v-col
        xl="3"
        lg="3"
        md="3"
        sm="6"
        cols="12"
    >
        <div class="d-flex align-center">
        <div>
            <v-img
            src="../../../../assets/icons/calendar.svg"
            width="20"
            ></v-img>
        </div>
        <span class="pl-2 text-subtitle-2">{{ student.time }}</span>
        </div>
    </v-col>
    <v-col
        xl="3"
        lg="3"
        md="3"
        sm="12"
        cols="12"
    >
        <v-btn
        width="100%"
        class=""
        :color="getColorBtn(student.status, student.isCorrect, student.isRemind)"
        >
        <v-icon
            v-show="isHide"
            class="mr-2"
            :class="getIcon(student.status, student.isCorrect, student.isRemind)"
        >
            {{ getIcon(student.status, student.isCorrect, student.isRemind) }}
        </v-icon>
        {{ textButton(student.status, student.isCorrect, student.isRemind) }}
        </v-btn>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

And now, I want to change it using Switch Case. But I still have no idea to make it works. Is it possible to have multiple case and also multiple result?

Based on my research at google and what I've tried to is just like this. And maybe it's just the logic, not the right syntax base on my case/data :

```
var buttonColor = ''
var buttonText = ''
var buttonIcon = ''
if (status = 1) {
    switch(isCorrect, isRemind) {
        case '1':
        case '1':
            buttonColor = 'v-btn--outlined theme--light primary--text'
            buttonText = 'Corrected'
            buttonIcon = ''
            break;
        case '0':
        case '1':
            buttonColor = 'primary plain--text'
            buttonText = 'Correction'
            buttonIcon = ''
            break;
        default:
            buttonColor = 'v-btn v-btn--text theme--light primary--text shadow-none'
            buttonText = 'Remind'
            buttonIcon = mdiBellOutline
            break;
    }
} else {
    switch(isCorrect, isRemind) {
        case '0':
        case '0':
            buttonColor = 'v-btn--outlined theme--light primary--text'
            buttonText = 'Remind'
            buttonIcon = mdiBellOutline
            break;
        case '0':
        case '1':
            buttonColor = 'v-btn v-btn--text theme--light success--text shadow-none'
            buttonText = 'Reminded'
            buttonIcon = mdiCheckBellOutline
            break;
        default:
            buttonColor = 'v-btn v-btn--text theme--light primary--text shadow-none'
            buttonText = 'Remind'
            buttonIcon = mdiBellOutline
            break;
    }

    return buttonColor
    return buttonText
    return buttonIcon
}
```

How to make it work? Your help means a lot. Thank u in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can map your options in new data function property, and then adjust your students array with computed property (you can easily add more cases if needed, just update options array):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      isHide: true,
      /*icons: {
        mdiBellOutline,
        mdiBellCheckOutline,
      },*/
      students: [
        { no: '1', name: 'Ridho Mckinnon', status: 1, time: ' 08:04 - 09:58, 19/01/2021', isCorrect: 1, isRemind: 1,},
        { no: '2', name: 'Ridho Mckinnon', status: 1, time: ' 08:04 - 09:58, 19/01/2021', isCorrect: 0, isRemind: 1,},
        { no: '3', name: 'Ridho Mckinnon', status: 0, time: ' 08:04 - 09:58, 19/01/2021', isCorrect: 0, isRemind: 1,},
        { no: '4', name: 'Ridho Mckinnon', status: 0, time: ' 08:04 - 09:58, 19/01/2021', isCorrect: 0, isRemind: 0,},
      ],
      //  new data property with mappings
      options: [
        {type: [1,1,1], color: 'v-btn--outlined theme--light primary--text', txt: 'Corrected', icon: 'd-none'},
        {type: [1,0,1], color: 'primary plain--text', txt: 'Correction', icon: 'd-none'},
        {type: [0,0,1], color: 'v-btn v-btn--text theme--light success--text shadow-none', txt: 'Reminded', icon: ''},
        {type: [0,0,0], color: 'v-btn v-btn--text theme--light primary--text shadow-none', txt: 'Remind', icon: ''}
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    //  computed property for adjusting your array
    getStudents() {
      const result = []
      this.students.forEach(s => {
        this.options.forEach(o => {
          if ([s.status, s.isCorrect, s.isRemind] == ''+o.type) {
            s.color = o.color
            s.txt = o.txt
            s.icon = o.icon
            result.push(s)
          }
        })
      })
      return result
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getColorChip(status) {
      return status === 1 ? 'v-chip-light-bg success--text' : 'v-chip-light-bg error--text'
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
                               <!--  loop with computed property -->
        <v-row v-for="student in getStudents" :key="student.no">
          <v-col xl="2" lg="2" md="2" sm="6" cols="12">
            <v-chip
            class="text-subtitle-2 text-md-caption text-lg-caption text-xl-caption"
            :color="getColorChip(student.status)"
            >
              {{ `${student.status ? 'Active': 'Nonactive'} ` }}
            </v-chip>
          </v-col>
          <v-col xl="3" lg="3" md="3" sm="6" cols="12">
            <div class="d-flex align-center">
              <div>
                <v-img src="../../../../assets/icons/calendar.svg" width="20"></v-img>
              </div>
              <span class="pl-2 text-subtitle-2">{{ student.time }}</span>
            </div>
          </v-col>
          <v-col xl="3" lg="3" md="3" sm="12" cols="12">
            <v-btn width="100%" :color="student.color">
              <v-icon v-show="isHide" class="mr-2" :class="student.icon">
                {{ student.icon }}
              </v-icon>
              {{ student.txt }}
            </v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```